# Function remove(atOffsets:) complains about wrong type only at runtime

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this pretty simple code in Playground. It compiles without errors, but when I try to run it, I get an error with `remove(atOffsets:)` function. Why is that?

```
enum CandyColor: CaseIterable {
    case red, green, yellow, brown
}
enum CandyFilling: CaseIterable {
    case chocolade, nuts
}

extension CaseIterable {
    static var random: Self {
        Self.allCases.randomElement()!
    }
}

typealias Candy = (color: CandyColor, filling: CandyFilling)

var candies = (0...20).map{ _ in Candy(color: CandyColor.random, filling: CandyFilling.random)}

var redWithChocolade = [Candy]()
var yellowWithNuts = [Candy]()
var brownAndGreenWithChocolade = [Candy]()

var indiciesToRemove = IndexSet()
for (index, candy) in candies.enumerated() {
    switch candy {
    case (.red, .chocolade):
        redWithChocolade.append(candy)
        indiciesToRemove.insert(index)
    case (.yellow, .nuts):
        yellowWithNuts.append(candy)
        indiciesToRemove.insert(index)
    case let(c) where [.brown, .green].contains(c.color) && c.filling == .chocolade:
        brownAndGreenWithChocolade.append(c)
        indiciesToRemove.insert(index)
    default:
        break
    }
}

candies.remove(atOffsets: indiciesToRemove) // Error: candidate expects value of type 'Int' for parameter #1

print("Left in heap: \(candies)")
```

Comment: It works fine on XCode 12.5, what a version of XCode do you have?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 13.0 (13A233), @iUrii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add:

```swift
import SwiftUI
```

to your script because it contains `remove(atOffsets:)` implementation and XCode doesn't import this framework implicitly.

Comment: Somehow it helped, though I had `import UIKit` statement already and it should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use just `filter(_:)` instead?

```
let leftOver = candies.filter { candy in 
    switch candy {
    case (.red, .chocolade): 
        redWithChocolade.append(candy)
        return false
    case (.yellow, .nuts):
         yellowWithNuts.append(candy)
         return false
     case (.brown, .chocolade):
         fallthrough
     case (.green, .chocolade):
         brownORGreenWithChocolade.append(candy)
         return false
      default: return true
    }
}
```

Or in case you really need in-place removal, `removeAll(where:)`:

```
candies.removeAll { candy in 
    switch candy {
    case (.red, .chocolade): 
        redWithChocolade.append(candy)
        return true
    case (.yellow, .nuts):
         yellowWithNuts.append(candy)
         return true
     case (.brown, .chocolade):
         fallthrough
     case (.green, .chocolade):
         brownORGreenWithChocolade.append(candy)
         return true
      default: return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought deleting several indexes at once is an efficient approach. And mainly the question was about why obvious thing does not work. But your suggestion looks interesting and handy.

Comment: The Functional Programming approach I've suggested should perform better than iterating through the elements two times: one to get the indices to delete and another one to delete elements at those indices.
Doing everything by looping elements just one time is possible by either adopting `filter(_:)` or `removeAll(where:)`.